# Magento 2.4.5 pdf downloaded using mpdf not showing logo image

Tags: pdf, magento2, mpdf, magento2.4

Hi I'm using mpdf(in mageplaza module) to download my invoices as pdf in my magento 2.4.5 project and I get this issue of logo image not visible in downloaded pdf files recently. Earlier it was working fine. A red cross is showing for the logo as following

[image]

This issue is only in my aws server instances in my local env it's working fine.
After I enabled image errors for mdpf using

```
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
```

I get this error "Could not find image file (https://uat.xxxxxx.com/media/mageplaza/pdfinvoice/default/logo.png)"

The only change I have done recently for my prod env was using cloudflare.And I have checked if it has blocked any paths and it's not blocking any.

Requesting your help!

Comment: how about using an image file instead?

Comment: Did you check if the image exists in the above mentioned path, or it's accessable?

Comment: @Duke yes it exists in the path

Comment: @Raptor which means?

Comment: @SahanThilakarathna Did you check your error logs, there should be something there and also check your GD version in both local and production instances. However, check with a jpg image, instead of a png for testing purposes.

Comment: @SahanThilakarathna Can you show the codes that you add the logo?